# Loading Flutter Svg

Tags: flutter, svg

The following error shows when i try to open the svg, I have the svg declared and also flutter_svg in the pubspec.yaml. Unsure as to why its not able to load the asset.

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: "assets/map.svg".
The asset does not exist or has empty data.
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:254:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: "assets/map.svg".
The asset does not exist or has empty data.
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:254:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: "assets/map.svg".
The asset does not exist or has empty data.
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:254:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I was wondering if there is something incompatible with my svg in flutter as it has pre-existing onclick events. Although I couldn't find anything on it. The code for the svg is too large to paste in put I will attach segments of parts i was wondering that could be issues.

```
svg width="940" height="940"


xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

<g id="TITLE">
<text x="425" y="10" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="700" font-family="Helvetica"  font-size="15px"></text>
</g>
<g id="LEGEND">
<text x="98.8075" y="87.9701" font-family="Helvetica"  font-weight="700"  font-size="9px">Branch Color</text>
<rect x="89.807" y="79.125" fill="#D3D3D3" width="2.333" height="154"/>
<rect x="99.208" y="98.125" fill="#FA6958" width="6.584" height="6.584"/>
<text x="110.8889" y="102.625" font-weight="700"  font-size="5" font-family="Helvetica">AGC</text>
<rect x="99.208" y="112.125" fill="#3F9FFC" width="6.584" height="6.584"/>
<text x="110.8889" y="116.625" font-weight="700"  font-size="5" font-family="Helvetica">Atypical</text>
<rect x="99.208" y="126.125" fill="#FAD53F" width="6.584" height="6.584"/>
```

```
g id="LABELS">
<a xlink:href="http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q2M2I8" target="_blank"><text id="t_x5F_AAK1" x="346.8112" y="368.3386" font-weight="700"  font-size="4px" fill="#000000" font-family="'Helvetica'" letter-spacing=".035">AAK1</text></a>
<a xlink:href="http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P00519" target="_blank"><text id="t_x5F_ABL1" x="271.5105" y="179.8826" font-weight="700"  font-size="4px" fill="#000000" font-family="'Helvetica'" letter-spacing=".035">Abl</text></a>
<a xlink:href="http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P42684" target="_blank"><text id="t_x5F_ABL2" x="269.2045" y="175.3099" font-weight="700"  font-size="4px" fill="#000000" font-family="'Helvetica'" letter-spacing=".035">Arg</text></a>
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class MapPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/map.svg',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Also include the asset part of pubspec.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There can be the following possibilities:

**1st (Most probable):**
Your mentioned svg name 'map.svg' or svg file address 'assets/map.svg' isn't accurate, some typo maybe. Very basic.

**2nd:**
Your pubspec.yaml file has bad indentation.
You should have 2 spaces before "assets:" and 4 spaces before "- assets/", just like:

```
flutter:
    
  assets:
    - assets/
```

[Screenshot for 2nd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQvgK.png)

**3rd:**
Your flutter svg package might be broken/outdated.
Run this command in your terminal:

```
flutter pub add flutter_svg
```

and then update dependencies.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you it was an outdated dependency

Comment: @archie You are welcome, it's been a few months but still I would request you to mark my answer as accepted if it helped even a bit. TIA